# How to get logged in username when running Powershell as Administrator?

Tags: windows, powershell

I tried to run this command in powershell:
`(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Username`

But it prints me an empty string.

Is there a command to get the output? this command worked for me on other machine but not on different machine.

Worked on machine with version of powershell:
Major: 5
Minor: 1
Build: 19041
Revision: 1682

Did not work on powershell version:
Major: 5
Minor: 1
Build: 17763
Revision: 2931

Comment: The username associated with the current session is stored in `$env:USERNAME`

Comment: Which user? As you don't want the process user, do you want the user that logged in on the welcome screen or the user Explorer (taskbar) is running as?

Comment: @Anders the welcome screen